# error when using requestForegroundPermissionsAsync() expo-location

Tags: react-native, expo, geolocation, location

I'm facing a problem when using expo location, before a dialog box appeared to accept activating my GPS but it stopped working, I've tried many ways to adjust it and even use other libs but I can't get this dialog box to appear again:

follow the example:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrQi3.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2aZf.png)

error message:

```
Error: Encountered an exception while calling native method: Exception occurred while executing exported method getCurrentPositionAsync on module ExpoLocation: Found interface com.google.android.gms.location.SettingsClient, but class was expected (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.location.SettingsClient' appears in /data/app/~~9V2H4GV4hc3TbZv2GkLUkQ==/com.nagumo.tracker-qcA3R0SsVgaxG4wtLsqJlA==/base.apk)    
Error: Encountered an exception while calling native method: Exception occurred while executing exported method getCurrentPositionAsync on module ExpoLocation: Found interface com.google.android.gms.location.SettingsClient, but class was expected (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.location.SettingsClient' appears in /data/app/~~9V2H4GV4hc3TbZv2GkLUkQ==/com.nagumo.tracker-qcA3R0SsVgaxG4wtLsqJlA==/base.apk)
```

I have already carried out gradle cleaning among other tests but without success

```
 useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            let { status } = await Location.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync();
            // let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
            if (status !== 'granted') {
                setErrorMsg('Permissão para acessar a localização foi negada');
                return;
            } else {
                await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();

            }

            let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
            setLocation(location);

        })
    }, [])
```